# Does duplicate keys or extra key values as a part of ResquestBody JSON should result in Bad request in REST environment?

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am new to REST environment, I have a very simple bean called Operations with the following properties

```
public class Operations
{
String operationName,
int operationPriority,
boolean isOperationParallel,
boolean expirationPolicy
}
```

so to create a Operations bean the request JSON would be

```
'{
  "operationName": "NewOperation",
  "operationPriority": 2,
  "isOperationParallel": false,
  "expirationPolicy": 30
}'
```

On server side to map the request JSON to Operations bean the I have use Spring ResquestBody, which by default, given duplicate keys it overrides with the last key value for example if below is the request then , `operationName` will be `NewOperationTwo`

```
'{
      "operationName": "NewOperation",
      "operationName": "NewOperationTwo",
      "operationPriority": 2,
      "isOperationParallel": false,
      "expirationPolicy": 30
    }'
```

Now I have been told by our QA that it should lead to `400 BAD_REQUEST` as HTTP status response.I am also told that it should also lead to 400 response if an unknown property like "Dog":"Barks" is also passed as part of the request-body, which is also ignored by Jackson by default.

Now my point is, I am ok to send `400`  by parsing the request and finding the duplicate and unknown properties but is this overhead required? Because if it was a mandate then Spring would have returned a `BAD_REQUEST` response by default which it doesn't.

Could anyone help me in this as what a standard REST API response would be for duplicate and unknown keys in request body and what would be the consequences if I don't throw BAD_REQUEST as a response?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Standard REST API response defined for duplicate and unknown Key in Json. However If you are using `Content-Type` like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `mulitpart/from-data` the request parameter names should be unique . This doen't apply for JSON . As it can not be determined what json fromat will be in each application .

So it is upto the orginazation's business requirement that determine how situations like this should be handled . And it is Software developer role to implement this constrains in the application .

So if your QA Engineer Say that 400 status should be sent back for duplicate
 and unknown fields  . It has to done like that

**Update**

If the JSON Request/response  structure is fixed . Then you can use JAXB and design pattern Objects like Value Object(VO) to regular POJOs to handle the incoming and outgoing data . 
Use JAXB to bind Json to java objects and after that you can use framework provided evaluation features .   It will reduce significant amount of effort you would have put without it . If you are using Jersey go through fallowing link to have more idea

[JAXB support in jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html)

[bean validation support in Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply , this is exactly what i am sayings, it is not mandate like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `mulitpart/from-data ` , if it was then what would be the difference between form-data and response body , also why to take the overhead what would be the consequences,for now its a small JSON what if it an very large nested complex JSON then how much processing it will take.

Comment: looked in to your solution , but found more easy one. please see the update 2 for more explanation.

Comment: In that case you can post answer for your own question . So that others will have access to the knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response on solution, but this is what I gone forward with,

I created a custom HttpMessageConverter for jackson, Initially I was confused between MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter  & MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter
but read on Jackson and gone with MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.

So below is the custom message converter,basically it is need to override three methods of which

```
read(Type type, Class<?> contextClass, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
                    throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException
```

was the method that would contain the message from the request body and pass it to the ObjectMapper

```
public class CustomMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    private static final Logger logger =

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private boolean prefixJson = false;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter#setPrefixJson(boolean)
     */
    @Override
    public void setPrefixJson(boolean prefixJson) {
        this.prefixJson = prefixJson;
        super.setPrefixJson(prefixJson);
    }


    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter#read(java.lang.reflect.Type,
     * java.lang.Class, org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage)
     */
    @Override
    public Object read(Type type, Class<?> contextClass, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
                    throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, true);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, true);
        objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION, true);

        InputStream istream = inputMessage.getBody();
        String responseString = IOUtils.toString(istream);
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(responseString, OperatorTokenDefinition.class);
        } catch (UnrecognizedPropertyException ex) {
           throw new YourCustomExceptionClass();
        } catch (InvalidFormatException ex) { 
           throw new YourCustomExceptionClass();
        } catch (IgnoredPropertyException ex) {
            throw new YourCustomExceptionClass();
        } catch (JsonMappingException ex) {
            throw new YourCustomExceptionClass();
        } catch (JsonParseException ex) {
            logger.error("Could not read JSON JsonParseException:{}", ex);
            throw new YourCustomExceptionClass();
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter#supports(java.lang.Class)
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter#writeInternal(java.lang.Object,
     * org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage)
     */
    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object arg0, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
                    throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(arg0);
        outputMessage.getBody().write(json.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    private ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("messages");
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Now only we need to register the Custom MessageConverter with the spring context.In the configuration class.Below is the code

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    CustomMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter =
                    CustomMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    List<MediaType> mediaTypeList = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    mediaTypeList.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypeList);
    converters.add(jsonConverter);
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```